# Change tracking in sql server 2008, senseless delete operations

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am currently testing change tracking mechanism in sql server 2008 and noticed something:

When to the base table (change tracked) I insert a new record and delete it using the same
key, select with the changes returns to me the information that it should be deleted in the remote table however that record doesn't exist at all in that table ..

Why is it functioning that way?

SAMPLE CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER primary key,
  value int
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].Test
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING   

SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()   

SELECT CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.ID, IV.value   
  FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TEST, 51374) CT
  LEFT JOIN TEST IV ON IV.ID = CT.ID  

--zero changes now for: 51374

insert into Test VALUES ('54C1D80E-ACB0-433F-94DF-7D06FE809E22', 1)
delete from Test where id = '54C1D80E-ACB0-433F-94DF-7D06FE809E22'

select * from Test -- table is empty (insert and delete)

SELECT CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.ID, IV.value   
  FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TEST, 51374) CT
  LEFT JOIN TEST IV ON IV.ID = CT.ID  

--however for Anchor: 51374 it claims I should delete the record ...
```

My base and the remote table were  in sync at 51374 anchor.
Adding and deleting the record shouldn't give me the info for deleting 
of something I don't have in my remote table ...

Comment: It's all there in the documentation, really "Only the fact that a row has changed is required, not how many times the row has changed or the values of any intermediate changes.", "If an application requires information about all the changes that were made and the intermediate values of the changed data, using change data capture, instead of change tracking"

Comment: I don't need the info of all changes, but when The row with ID: 1 had been inserted and deleted after Time x (the client has anchor at time x), why "Change tracking" gives me the info I should delete something which I don't have ... I don;t understand it.

Comment: Imagine if there's a row with ID 1 that you know about. Then in some period, someone goes in and deletes that row, and then adds a new row with the same ID. Change tracking will give you an insert, even though you already knew about a row with ID 1 and haven't seen a delete. It's the nature of the beast - you only get the last change, and you have to reconcile that with your version of reality. If you see a Delete for a row you don't know about, *ignore it*.

Comment: Ok last operation, but in case I have to synchronize mobile application with the central server, transfer data to change over GSM,   and execute delete statement on something which doesn't exist is senseless. I don't need info about last delete operation in case insert/delete operation occurred after last sync time...

Comment: You can't have both "I don't need information about all changes" and "if these specific sequence of changes occurs, I want to do something different"

Comment: Last operation is useful. But for me it is obvious that engine could be smart enough to not return these operations between lastSyncAnchor and currentAnchor when the record between these two was inserted and deleted ...

Comment: Okay, so as the engine is about to replace the "this row was inserted" record with the "this row was deleted" record, it decides to instead completely discard the information. It can do this during the brief period where it knows what the previous change was and what it's about to record. You've solved the problem. Except for any sequence where (one or more) update occurred between the insert and the delete. Now the previous change was an update, not the insert, so it can't do this special case logic you want it to - you still get this phantom delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think Damien's answer is right.  Not sure why he answered in a comment.

> It's all there in the documentation, really "Only the fact that a row
> has changed is required, not how many times the row has changed or the
> values of any intermediate changes.", "If an application requires
> information about all the changes that were made and the intermediate
> values of the changed data, using change data capture, instead of
> change tracking."
>
> Imagine if there's a row with ID 1 that you know about. Then in some
> period, someone goes in and deletes that row, and then adds a new row
> with the same ID. Change tracking will give you an insert, even though
> you already knew about a row with ID 1 and haven't seen a delete. It's
> the nature of the beast - you only get the last change, and you have
> to reconcile that with your version of reality. If you see a Delete
> for a row you don't know about, ignore it.